# Creating multiple maps in hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am using ***Hazelcast 3.8.1***

I already have one map(`<map name="default">`) configured and **want to add a new(separate)** map to the instances.

**Questions:**

- Can we use multiple maps tag in hazelcast config?
- If yes, how can we retrieve different config for different maps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define as many maps as you want in the configs. Moreover, you can [use wildcards](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.1/manual/html-single/index.html#using-wildcards) to define a config for multiple maps at once. 
Once you do a `hazelcastInstance.getmap("myMap")` it will fetch the config with the name `"myMap"`.